# cocoa: not able to get property value from another class?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a property in my CustomClass1:
@property(assign)NSString *url;

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener{
_url= [[request URL] absoluteString] ;
NSLog(@"requested url is %@",_url);
NSInteger index=[_tabView numberOfTabViewItems];
NSTabViewItem *newItem=[[NSTabViewItem alloc] init];
[_tabView insertTabViewItem:newItem atIndex:index];
[newItem setLabel:@"Empty Tab" ];
//[_tabView  selectPreviousTabViewItem:@"select"];
[self initializeWebView:newItem];
[[_tabView .tabViewItems objectAtIndex:index] setView:[newVC view]];
 // NSLog(@"requested url is %@",url);
```

}

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

CustomClass1 *obj=[[CustomClass1 alloc] init];
NSLog(@"url is %@",[obj url]);
[[_newWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.url]]];
```

}

how can i get the value of _url in my awakefromnib method in Viewcontroller class?
NSlog is returning null.
how can i resolve this issue?
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your "`url`" property needs to be allocated and initialized to *something* before it can return something other than "`nil`".

You could set your "`url`" property's contents in the "`init`" method of your "`CustomClass1`" object, but there's a bit of a trick to doing this ([see this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056188/should-i-refer-to-self-property-in-the-init-method-with-arc)).