# NSArray initialization in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm using Xcode 5, the problem is in the following two `self.<something>` assignment statement Xcode says that **expected expression**,  and also on return statement.

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    ​ ​ ​ self.questions​ ​=​ ​[NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ @​"​F​r​o​m​ ​w​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​c​o​g​n​a​c​ ​m​a​d​e​?​"​, ​@​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​7​+​7​?​"​, @​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​t​h​e​ ​c​a​p​i​t​a​l​ ​o​f​ ​V​e​r​m​o​n​t​?​",nil​]​;

    ​ ​ ​ ​se​l​f​.​a​n​s​w​e​r​s​ ​=​ [NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ ​@​"​G​r​a​p​e​s​"​,@​"​1​4​"​,@​"​M​o​n​t​p​e​l​i​e​r​"​,nil]​; 

   }
​ ​ ​ ​r​e​t​u​r​n​ ​self;
}
```

Comment: Show the `@interface` definition.

Comment: inside init method don't use self.questions , always use the baking variable _question =

Comment: @Spynet That isn't true is it.

Comment: @trojanfoe well you should use the `_propertyName` and not the `self.propertyname` in init and dealloc since this will make sure KVO will not get fired and makes is more thread save.

Comment: guys i think that was xCode issue, when i copy pasted this code it generated this exception, but now when i manually type it there is no issue

Comment: @trojanfoe that is wrong if i type that means works perfect so don't copy and paste just type will solve your problem

Comment: @rckoenes Obviously you need to write code that avoids side-effects, and one way is to avoid the use of setter methods, however even using the instance variable you can still cause side-effects by calling methods on the object when the object is not fully initialised.  So there is no blanket-rule about using `self` within `init`, just that you need to understand it.  However this is not what this question is about.

Comment: @trojanfoe same my point, i'm telling everyone so that if same problem occurs u can also remind this perspective :)

Comment: iOS_Developer/Spynet: Sorry I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

When writing the `init` methods of your code, don't access your instance variables like `self.<something>` you should be doing it using the direct access way of `_<something` so change the

```
self.questions​ ​=​ ​[NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ @​"​F​r​o​m​ ​w​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​c​o​g​n​a​c​ ​m​a​d​e​?​"​, ​@​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​7​+​7​?​"​, @​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​t​h​e​ ​c​a​p​i​t​a​l​ ​o​f​ ​V​e​r​m​o​n​t​?​",nil​]​;

​se​l​f​.​a​n​s​w​e​r​s​ ​=​ [NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ ​@​"​G​r​a​p​e​s​"​,@​"​1​4​"​,@​"​M​o​n​t​p​e​l​i​e​r​"​,nil]​;
```

too

```
_questions​ ​=​ ​[NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ @​"​F​r​o​m​ ​w​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​c​o​g​n​a​c​ ​m​a​d​e​?​"​, ​@​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​7​+​7​?​"​, @​"​W​h​a​t​ ​i​s​ ​t​h​e​ ​c​a​p​i​t​a​l​ ​o​f​ ​V​e​r​m​o​n​t​?​",nil​]​;

_​a​n​s​w​e​r​s​ ​=​ [NSArray arrayWithObjects:​ ​@​"​G​r​a​p​e​s​"​,@​"​1​4​"​,@​"​M​o​n​t​p​e​l​i​e​r​"​,nil]​;
```

The reason for using direct access (`_<something>`) over the dot notation (`self.<something>`) is because the dot notation can trigger other side effects such as KVO or key-value observing as you may know it by.

A good answer that may help you is on [Initializing a property, dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733)

And [What is the correct way of init iVar variables in presence of ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035149/what-is-the-correct-way-of-init-ivar-variables-in-presence-of-arc)

And [Should I refer to self.property in the init method with ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056188/should-i-refer-to-self-property-in-the-init-method-with-arc/8056260#8056260)

And [Why would you use an ivar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar/9086811#9086811)

Comment: @Downvoter please leave reason for down vote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, however I expect the down vote was because your answer is not true.

Comment: @trojanfoe please note the other questions that I read before this which seem to all say the same thing, please correct me if I am wrong and misunderstood the answers on these questions then.

Comment: @trojanfoe has answer is not an answer to the question, but the answer is legit in that you should not use `self.` in `init` or `dealloc`.

Comment: @rckoenes Just so you are aware I am aware this doesn't fully answer the question however it was far to much to leave as a comment.

Comment: The issue with using property setters is that it's not obvious it can cause side-effects due to KVO and that is why instance variables are preferred in `init`/`dealloc`.  However at the end of the day you must understand the effect of calling any method of your object, within `init` or otherwise, and therefore there is no rule saying "thou shalt not use `self` in `init`".  The rule is "understand what calling a method (including setter) does".

Comment: @trojanfoe OK that's fair so it is only a slight misunderstanding, I will edit my answer to include this when I get a chance. I will just add this under my original answer as an edit