# How to access super class's variables in init method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Super class `Resource`

```
@interface Resource : CoderObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *resourceID;
@property (assign, nonatomic) ResourceType resourceType;
@property (assign, nonatomic) DataType dataType;

@end
```

Subclass `ViewResource`

```
@interface ViewResource : Resource

@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomView *view;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

In subclass `ViewResource`'s `init` method how to access `Resource`'s variable `dataType`? Now I'm trying to just use `super.dataType = ...`

Is there other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `self.dataType`. Your subclass has full visibility of all of the superclass properties defined in the .h file. Using `self.xxx` also gives you the ability to override the accessor methods if required in the future without coming back to edit all of your usage code.

Looking at your link below, fair enough. Those are all valid points. Accessors shouldn't have side effects but you can't guarantee they won't. If the property is defined the superclass then you have a couple of options:

1. Use `self.xxx` to set the property and endeavour to ensure no side effects
2. Call an init method on super, passing the required parameters, and set them there

Comment: But I heard that you shouldn't call `self.method` in `init` method?

Comment: What reason was given? It's preferable to use the accessor methods to set the value. The only time you shouldn't use the accessor is when you're inside the accessor.

Comment: Check this link:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW11

Comment: @Wain There is actually a big discussion about it. I prefer to always use accessors in init/dealloc but if your setters have custom implementation or they are overriden, sometimes you need to reorder the statements. Note that Apple does the same in UIKit.

Comment: I should call super class's init method.

Answer (score 0):

Like *Wain* stated in his answer you have direct access to your super's class members (if they are not private).

And there is no problem calling `self.property` in the init method as long as your init looks like this

```
-(id)initAndTheNameYoWantAndMaybeSomeParameters:(NSString *)paramExample {
    self = [super initNameOfAnInitMethodFromSuperClass];
    //check if the init was with success
    if(self != nil) {
       self.myStringProp = paramExample;
       //or
       self.propertyFromSuper = paramExample;
    }
}
```

Yes, you can also do stupid stuff in the initMethods (I did it before :)) ) like calling the same initMethod from inside it which was generating a recursive calling that was crashing my app. (Easy to spot this issue)