# Setting CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor with a UIColor that was passed as a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, uicolor

I'm having some problems with my code. I am unable to set the circle the color that was passed in the constructor. When it runs I receive the following error, " **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -CGColor not defined for the UIColor ; need to first convert colorspace.**'" Here is my code

MainViewController.m

```
#import "CircleGenerator.h"
CircleGenerator *newCircle =[[CircleGenerator alloc]initWithFrame:frame initWithColor:[UIColor blackColor];
```

CircleGenerator.h

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *circleColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame initWithColor:(UIColor*)color;
```

CircleGenerator.m

```
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame initWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _circleColor = [[UIColor alloc]init];
        _circleColor = color;

        NSLog(@"the color is %@", _circleColor);

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{


    // Init a CGContecRef
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Makes circle a bit smaller then the rectange to prevent it from getting cut off
    CGRect border = CGRectInset(rect, 5, 5);
    // Draws circle
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, border);
    // Changes the color of the line
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);
    // Sets the line to the appropriate thickness
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    // Draws the circle onto the UIView
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

I am having problems with the following line from CircleGenerator.m

```
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);
```

If I put [UIColor blackColor] in place of _circleColor, the code compiles without any problems. Any ideas with with what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: What do you get it the log inside init method.

Comment: I get the following **the color is UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1**

Comment: Try removing [[UIColor alloc] init]. I guess it is because of that, since it defines nothing, no color no colorspace.

Comment: Nothing changed after removing [[UIColor alloc]init]. I am still getting the same message from the log inside of the init method and I am still getting the same NSInvalidArgumentException error

Comment: Can you post the line(s) where you are calling this method?

Comment: I am calling the method from MainViewController.m and I am using the following code to initialize it, **CircleGenerator *newCircle =[[CircleGenerator alloc]initWithFrame:frame initWithColor:[UIColor blackColor];**

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);
```

With:

```
CGColorRef redRef = CFRetain(_circleColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);
// use redRef and when done release it:
CFRelease(redRef)
```

**Edit:**

See this link how to fix your problem [Accessing CGThings from NSThings or UIThings](http://amattn.com/p/arc_best_practices.html)

Comment: Shouldn't you use redRef at second line?

Answer (score 1):

> _circleColor = [[UIColor alloc] init];

This returns the instance of the class UIPlaceholderColor and probably has no information about color space needed to make CGColor.

Try `_circleColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

You should create a color with designated initializer or use the color from preset like [UIColor blackColor].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not solve the problem. I am still receiving the same errors as before.

Answer (score 0):

What ever calls your init constructor has decreased the retain count of color. Since you are bypassing color's setter by assigning directly to _circleColor, the assignment does not increase the retain count - resulting in a dangling pointer.

Replace `_circleColor = color;` with `self.circleColor = color;`

Comment: Originally, I was using the color's setter method and I was still having the same exact problem.

Comment: Before this `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);` put `NSAssert(_circleColor, @"Must never be nil.);` to assert its not nil.

Comment: I added the code and it does show that the pointer is not nil. Nothing new was printed in the console. I am still receiving the same error as before. If i put a breakpoint right before `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [_circleColor CGColor]);`, it shows me that _circleColor is not nil, (or so I think). Here is what xcode shows **_circleColor UICachedDeviceWhiteColor * 0x10af06800 0x000000010af06800**

Comment: It is strongly recommended **against** to reference properties via the `self.` accessors within the `init` routine.  Yes, sometimes it appears to work but, in general, it's *a bad idea*.  (Apple docs).

Comment: @Olie Why? The parent constructor has been called and the code is guarded by a conditional check on `self`.

Comment: @Pétur I totally get what you're saying, but that's advice I've gotten both in official documentation (can't find at the moment) and from several friends who work at Apple on iOS.  <shrug>.

Comment: Here's a decent answer that talks about some of the pitfalls of using `self.` in `init`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056260/34820