# UISwipGestureRecognizer crash

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm asking for your help for i think a simple problem but i didn't manage to understand what's happening with my view.
I'm displaying an OpengGL view launched by my UIViewController like this:

```
  //OpenGL view init
CGRect mainframe=CGRectMake(0,0,768,708);
GLView= [[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:mainframe];
```

So then it is displayed well, but i tried to add a swipe gesture recognizer to call a function on this view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        ...  

        oneFingerSwipeRight =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeRight:)];
        oneFingerSwipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

        oneFingerSwipeLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeLeft:)];
        oneFingerSwipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

        [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then when the view appear, i'm doing the action swiping on the right or on the left and this appear in the terminal:

**2012-04-17 12:00:15.735 MultipleViewsApp[4372:f803] -[OpenGLView transitionCubeLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd38bd0
2012-04-17 12:00:15.736 MultipleViewsApp[4372:f803]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OpenGLView transitionCubeLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcd38bd0'
 **First throw call stack:
(0x1764052 0x18f5d0a 0x1765ced 0x16caf00 0x16cace2 0x622e39 0x622143 0x6233cf 0x625a31 0x62598c 0x61e3e7 0x386812 0x386ba2 0x36d384 0x360aa9 0x293dfa9 0x17381c5 0x169d022 0x169b90a 0x169adb4 0x169accb 0x293c879 0x293c93e 0x35ea9b 0x2518 0x2475)**

my functions "transitionCubeLeft"/"transitionCubeLeft" contains just an NSLOG but nothing else relevant for this.
I'll be very gratefull if someone could help me to understand this problem.
thankss

Comment: can you post the code for the "transitionCubeLeft"/"transitionCubeLeft" methods? off topic: please take care of your memory management: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5932733/644629

Comment: Also, what's the name of the class your posted code is in and what is its parent class?

Comment: the two function transition 
`-(void)transitionCubeRight{
    NSLog(@"RIGHT");
    borne=angle+90;
}
-(void)transitionCubeLeft{
    NSLog(@"LEFT");
    borne=angle-90;
}`

Comment: @philip Mills
The parent class is UIView, but i had the same problem when i tried to put all that code in my viewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `transitionCubeLeft`/`transitionCubeRight` defined without parameters.

Change

```
 oneFingerSwipeRight =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeRight:)];
 oneFingerSwipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

 oneFingerSwipeLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeLeft:)];
 oneFingerSwipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

 [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];
 [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];
```

to

```
 oneFingerSwipeRight =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeRight)];
 oneFingerSwipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

 oneFingerSwipeLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(transitionCubeLeft)];
 oneFingerSwipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

 [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];
 [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have not defined **transitionCubeLeft** method. Try to find out if it is defined and the count of parameters of the method is 1, according to the selecter you are using.

Comment: it was the problem :s
Actually I put ":" because i needed one parameter but after a while i decided not to put this parameter and i forgot to delete the ":"

Thanks again ! Sometimes the most obvious mistakes are the hardest to find

Comment: @Bobyblanco now you will remember it for the rest of your life :)