# Master Detail Storyboard: Table View not showing cells (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I'm having troubles with the master viewController not showing any cells. This is the situation:

The app uses storyboard.

When the app launches, it goes to the navigationController

A button is pressed and connected to the table ViewController and it's set to "push" to it.

I've added the object and made a cell/detailView or whatever.

For some reason, the cell won't show up!!!

Here's the files:

MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CraftingDetail.h"
#import "Crafting.h"

@class CraftingList;

@interface CraftingMaster : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CraftingDetail *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CraftingList *CL;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "CraftingMaster.h"
#import "CraftingList.h"

@interface CraftingMaster ()

@end

@implementation CraftingMaster

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize CL;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.CL = [[CraftingList alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for     this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return  self.CL.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.CL.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.CL craftingAtIndex:indexPath.row].Title;

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:      (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       // Delete the row from the data source
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
       // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and  add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc]   initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CraftingDetail : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Description;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but having an unexpectedly empty table view is a common issue when starting to develop with table views so hopefully this answer will be of use to someone.

Here are some things to check when your table view is devoid of cells and you expected otherwise:

- Are your data source object(s) (`self.CL` in this case) valid? (ie. Are they `!= nil` and point to the correct object?)
- Does `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` return an integer value greater than zero?
- Does `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`: return an integer value greater than zero?

Here are a couple of problems in MasterViewController.m above that need attention:

- `InitWithStyle:` will not be executed when the view controller is instantiated in a storyboard. Instead, `initWithCoder:` should be used. I suspect this was the source of JomanJi's pain as this resulted in `self.CL` not being instantiated. (As an aside, the data source object/property: `CL` should be instantiated by assigning the value to the `_CL` ivar directly, not to the property. See "[Initializing a property, dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733)" to learn why).
- Due to returning (what is likely) the same value for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` as `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` (ie. "`return self.CL.count;`"), the table view will display the same number of sections as there are cells in each section with each sections' cells containing the same data as the other sections. I doubt this effect was what the developer intended. (This is of course unless the `count` accessor method in `CraftingList` does something really strange).

Without seeing the code for `CraftingList` it is impossible to determine exactly what the problem is. However, given the age of the question, I suspect JomanJi has since figured it out on his/her own.

Comment: Hey, thanx for the answer, I'm not really working on this anymore, but I might consider it for later use, thanks again

Comment: No problem. Didn't think you were, but thought others might be interested to know why they aren't seeing anything in their table views. (I know I did when it happened to me!)