# initialising super init and other

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im getting the following error:

```
on the line self = [super init];
```

cannot assign self outside method init family

also getting yellow triangles on all self.whatever = whatever;

local declaration of "whatever" hides instance variable

```
@synthesize firstName, lastName, emailAdress, password, admin;

//current course funkade med nil men inte @"" vrf ;P
-(id) init
{
    return [self initwithName:@"" lastName:@"" password:@"" admin:@"" currentCourse:nil];
}

-(id) initwithName:(NSString *) firstName
          lastName:(NSString *) lastName
          password:(NSString *) password
             admin:(NSString *) admin
     currentCourse:(NSDictionary *) course
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.firstName = firstName;
        self.lastName = lastName;
        self.password = password;
        self.admin = admin;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: change `initwithName` for `initWithName`, uppercase W

Comment: that worked, geez sometimes my dyslexia is really getting the best of me :P thanks alot!

Comment: glad it helps you, furthermore you should avoid using self.whatever in the init methods, take a look to this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/5932733/1411844

Comment: @tkanzakic oh, im actually learning obj-c in school and my teacher never said anything about this :O thanks!!!

Comment: I wish they taught me Objective-C in school :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have synthesized `@synthesize firstName, lastName, emailAdress, password, admin;`

And in your method you are using same name

```
-(id) initwithName:(NSString *) firstName
          lastName:(NSString *) lastName
          password:(NSString *) password
             admin:(NSString *) admin
     currentCourse:(NSDictionary *) course
```

Change these to something else or remove synthesize, if your compiler supports auto-synthesize

```
-(id) initWithName:(NSString *) aFirstName
          lastName:(NSString *) aLastName
          password:(NSString *) aPassword
             admin:(NSString *) aAdmin
     currentCourse:(NSDictionary *) aCourse
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.firstName = aFirstName;
        self.lastName = aLastName;
        self.password = aPassword;
        self.admin = aAdmin;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: when i do that i get error 
use of undeclared idetifier did you mean "whatever"

thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Or you can @synthesize firstName = _firstname; etc

Comment: @Tim: yea, this is 3rd way of doing, 1st was skip manual-synthesing if  he uses new compiler. 2nd Rename parameters.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i use latest verison of xcode does that mean i have new compiler?

Comment: @nalydbob: Yes, so now make a copy of your project and try commenting all your `@synthesize`, but rename the method as initWithName.....  And then you need to use `_firstName=aFirstName` etc

Answer (score 1):

Anoop has nailed the properties stuff, but your first problem remains unanswered.

My first post was 
"
I think that the reason you can't assign to self is that you're method signature for init is not correct.

I'm not 100% sure of this, but I think that for an implementation of X, init should return (X*)
"
which is bogus - (id) init; is completely valid.

The error message doesn't feel completely accurate for the following, but amongst your problems is that in - (id) init, you call [self initWith....], but at this point, self has not been set.  If you want to write that code once, you'll have to refactor, but the better solution, IMHO, is

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self) {
        self.firstName = @"";
        self.lastName = @"";
        self.password = @"";
        self.admin = @"";
    }
    return self;
}
```

For a bonus point, I'd also like to point out that you don't use/set course :)

Comment: @anoop, I know this, I'm trying to explain the first error, but stand by for an updated answer, as I now see the problem :)