# Objective-C properties - is using [self myProperty] or self.myProperty slower than myProperty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

I'm using Objective-C properties to handle retaining/releasing instance variables for me. In my class, i'm doing stuff like this:

```
self.myProperty = somethingIWantToRetain
[self.myProperty doSomeAction]
[self.myProperty doSomethingElse]
```

Is using [self myProperty] / self.myProperty slower than simply using myProperty for those lines where i'm not changing the value of myProperty? Eg would the following be faster?

```
self.myProperty = somethingIWantToRetain
[myProperty doSomeAction]
[myProperty doSomethingElse]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost certainly a little bit slower, but it's unlikely to matter much.

Referring to your ivar directly (with a naked `myProperty`) accesses the variable directly.  Referring to your property getter (with the equivalent `self.myProperty` or `[self myProperty]`) has to invoke a method, which will generally perform a `retain` and `autorelease` on your ivar.

However, method dispatch in Objective-C is very, very fast, and the retain/autorelease calls are pretty cheap as well, especially for objects that will likely not be destroyed when the autorelease pool is cleared. I would focus on readability and consistent style, and only worry about performance here when it becomes clear that you have performance bottlenecks to chase.

Answer (score 4):

To be precise, when you write `[myProperty doSomeAction]`, you are not actually accessing the property, but accessing the instance variable (used as the backing variable of the property) directly.

You only access the property (thru its setter and getter) with the dot-notation `[self.myProperty doSomeAction]` (or by calling the setter/getter explicitly like `[[self myProperty] doSomeAction]` which is an exact equivalent, as this is what the compiler translates to when compiling your code)

So when you write `[myProperty doSomeAction]`, as it access the variable directly — contrary to `[self.myProperty doSomeAction]` which calls the getter of `myProperty` thus making an additional method call / message send — then yes in theory it will be faster as you will gain one message dispatch.

But in practice you won't see any improvement, so there is no need to consider accessing the variable directly (and it will make you loose flexibility if you want to implement it another way later)

---

Moreover, if you use the Modern Runtime (which is the case if you code for any version of iOS, Legacy Runtime being only used in 32-bits Mac OSX), then explicitly defining the backing variable for the property is not needed anymore. Thus you can declare the `@property` in the .h and `@synthesize` it in the .m without any instance variable (the compiler will generate it for you at compile time), and in such case you won't be able to call the (non-existing) instance variable! (at least not before the `@synthesize` directive)

Comment: The last section of your answer is incorrect. There was at one point a compiler bug which prevented it, but it is possible to use the synthesized ivar. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592592/what-is-modern-runtime/6593459#6593459) to "What is modern runtime?".

Comment: Yes you're right I agree, I just wrote that for the sake of simplicity; Note anyway that you can only use the ivar *after* the @synthesize directive in the code. (Actually, I think it is better not to rely on the ivar if you haven't created it yourself, and only use the property directly in such cases). But thanks for pointing this out, this is good to know this is still a possibility ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax is equivalent to calling the getter, so the first snippet would be slower on the basis that you'll incur two additional dynamic dispatches.

That being said, the loss will be minor and obviously you'll gain the flexibility of being able to change the setter and getter at a later date (such as if you end up making that value implicit such that it's not technically stored in memory, or passing it off to a third object, or doing something asynchronous to store that may require you to block on the getter in some circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

Slower as in one more step in operation? Yes.
Slower as in noticeably or realistically slower? Absolutely not.

You have to remember that modern cpus run programs at several million operations per second. In virtually all languages, calling a getter method is essentially the same speed as accessing the ivar itself (especially when there's no other code in the getter method).

It's good habit to use getters rather than accessing the ivars directly though, so I wouldn't try to "speed things up" by ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be marginally faster, but it's unlikely that you'll improve performance noticeably by doing this kind of micro optimization. If you use `self.myProperty`, you could later decide to implement a different accessor method without having to change your code everywhere.