# Should I release an unused ivar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I set in my interface.h a property as

```
@porperty(nonatomic, retain) *foo;
```

If i don't use this ivar in my implementation should I release it in dealloc ?

Comment: Yes, you should - something outside your object may have set it to some object.

Comment: You should use ARC in your projects its way better in memory management

Comment: @AhmedZ. no, it isn't better.

Comment: (that's not to say it's *worse*. just pointing out that it is not factual and merely a statement of preference. It should read: "You should use ARC in your projects because I like it way better" or "You should look into ARC because it has the potential to simplify your program's memory management and abstracts a common source of problems". Reference counting isn't such a complex concept -- it worked for many years before GC and ARC were available, but it was a common source of frustration for people new to the concepts and conventions. MRC can actually be a good deal faster than ARC.)

Comment: @justin nycly elaborated. MRC...?

Comment: ARC is good as it saves time.. but Non ARC really teaches you how to handle your memory.. which is its goodness :)

Comment: @AhmedZ.: Manual Retain Count opposed to Automatic Retain Count (ARC)

Comment: oh got it now. MRC = Non ARC environment. Thanks @Antzi

Comment: @AhmedZ. ARC = Automatic Reference Counting (i.e. compiler adds reference count operations). MRC = Manual Reference Counting (i.e. writing reference count operations where necessary). "MRC" isn't an official acronym; just a commonly used one which appeared after ARC.

Comment: and although *I* still do my own reference counting, I think ARC is the right choice for the typical app/team.

Comment: @H2CO3, if I release something that is not retain this should cause a problem ?

Comment: @FRChalaoux Yes. You don't release `weak` and `assign` properties. That's one reason I prefer setting the poperty to `nil` instead of releasing the backing ivar: the setters will **always** do the correct memory management step, but programmers won't.

Comment: @H2CO3, but if really no one retained my object counter will decrease to '-1', could it be a problem ?

Comment: @FRChalaoux No. An alive object's reference count is not 0, it's 1.

Comment: @H2CO3, you mean my object is not still alive ?

Comment: @H2CO3, You mean my property/synthesize keywords do not create my object thus I do not need to decrease its counter if no get have be been done !?

Comment: @FRChalaoux No, I don't mean that, but read Apple's memory management guide, everything is clearly explained in there, and I'm getting tired explaining this.

Comment: @H2CO3, I know this book but "Education is art of repetition", and I had a great pleasure to discuss with you, dear 'coach'. Bye.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // Other release code
    [_foo release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to @borrrden for the tip about avoiding setters during `dealloc`.

Comment: It is recommended not to use "self" in the dealloc method (for possible KVO problems) and instead to just release (and nil if you want to) the backing variable.

Comment: @borrrden Can you please provide a source for this recommendation.  My understanding is that you let the setter do the work for you, which means it must be invoked using `self`.

Comment: @trojanfoe [Is there any problem using self.property = nil in dealloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621139/is-there-any-problem-using-self-property-nil-in-dealloc), just have a look. ( its a new piece of info for me too)

Comment: @trojanfoe The link from MicRO shows a source :).  That understanding you have is true in general, *except* in init and dealloc.  The setter will take care of releasing the current value before retaining the new one.  In dealloc though, the new value is nil so it doesn't retain the new value (thus all that is left is releasing the old one).

Comment: @trojanfoe KVO isn't the only reason. this illustration may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932677/initializing-a-property-dot-notation/5932733#5932733

Comment: Why use _foo and not foo when you release it ?

Comment: @FRChalaoux because `[self.foo release]` is errnoneous - getters do a `- retain - autorelease` on the ivar.

Comment: @borrrden I disagree. Directly manipulating an ivar is not any better than setting the property to `nil`. And yes, I'm aware of the rant you linked, and I don't find it reasonable.

Comment: @ H2CO3, any reference on "getters do a - retain - autorelease on the ivar" ?

Comment: @H2CO3 That "rant" is quotes from the official Apple documentation...for another thing a subclass could have overridden the setter to do who knows what.

Answer (score -1):

yes you should **release**

for release you can write like this :

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // other release stuff

     if(foo != nil)
    {
       [foo release];

       foo = nil;
    }
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: The test against nil is unnecessary. You can send `release` to a nil object safely.

Comment: If he forgot to make it nil, then (foo != nil) condition is true and foo (a dangling pointer) will be released anyway, resulting in crash. It doesn't help in the case you mentioned.

Comment: yes man your right . i want to release if the object is not released yet.